# Nested queries to get count with two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have these 3 tables,

```
tbl_1-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware
2   |bbbb   |malware
3   |cccc   |ddos
3   |cccc   |trojan
4   |dddd   |ddos

tbl_2-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware
3   |cccc   |ddos
4   |dddd   |trojan
5   |eeee   |trojan
6   |ffff   |other

tbl_3-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |ddos
6   |ffff   |
2   |bbbb   |other
```

Which i need to get the result as follows,

```
result-
ip  |isp    |infection  |ipCount    |ispCount   |infectionCount
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware    |3          |3          |2
1   |aaaa   |ddos       |3          |3          |1
2   |bbbb   |other      |2          |2          |1
2   |bbbb   |malware    |2          |2          |1
3   |cccc   |ddos       |3          |3          |2
3   |cccc   |trojan     |3          |3          |1
4   |dddd   |ddos       |2          |2          |1
4   |dddd   |trojan     |2          |2          |1
5   |eeee   |trojan     |1          |1          |1
6   |ffff   |other      |2          |2          |1
6   |ffff   |           |2          |2          |1

ipCount, ispCount -> count of matching ip and isp
    eg-there are 3 records with ip = 1 and isp = aaaa

infectionCount -> count of matching infections per ip and isp
    eg-there are 2 infections that says malware where ip = 1 and isp = aaaa
```

I think I need a nested a query but I don't know how to count with two conditions; can you help?

**EDIT** : Code I tried,

```
SELECT ip, isp, infection, count(ip), count(isp), count(infection)
FROM (

SELECT ip, isp, infection
FROM tbl_1
UNION ALL
SELECT ip, isp, infectionType
FROM tbl_2
UNION ALL
SELECT ip, isp, infection
FROM tbl_3
)x

GROUP BY ip, isp, infection
```

But it doesnt give the result I desire cause I don't know how to do 2 types of counts in one query

Comment: So [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried unions, il post the code..

Comment: When is the `ipCount` different from the `ispCount`?

Comment: well its the same unless the isp name is different

Comment: @hims056 i posted the code i tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group column `infection` and (`ip` & `ipc`) differently then join them using sub-query like this:

```
SELECT t1.ip, t1.isp, t2.infection, t1.ipc, t1. ispc, t2.incount
FROM
    (SELECT ip, isp, infection, COUNT(ip) as ipc, COUNT(isp) as ispc
    FROM (
       SELECT ip, isp, infection
       FROM tbl1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ip, isp, infection
       FROM tbl2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ip, isp, infection
       FROM tbl3
       )x
     GROUP BY ip, isp) t1
JOIN
    (SELECT ip, isp, infection, COUNT(infection) as incount
     FROM (
       SELECT ip, isp, infection
       FROM tbl1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ip, isp, infection
       FROM tbl2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ip, isp, infection
       FROM tbl3
       )x
    GROUP BY ip, isp,  infection)t2
ON t1.ip = t2.ip
ORDER BY ip, isp, infection Desc
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56190/5)

**Note:** I think your desired output is wrong because:

1. In `Table3` there is no `infection` for `ip=6` but it is in your output
2. `infection` `other` is missing in your output (instead there is `malware`)

Comment: heheheee..thank you :) and yeaa..i made the edit..thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can union all the tables together then do a sum of the columns and group by the specific columns.

```
SELECT ip, isp, infection, COUNT(ip) AS ipcount, COUNT(isp) AS ispcount, COUNT(infection) AS infectioncount
FROM
  (
    SELECT ip, isp, infection
    FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ip, isp, infection
    FROM table_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ip, isp, infection
    FROM table_3
  )
GROUP BY ip, isp, infection
ORDER BY ip, isp, infection;
```

Comment: It is enough to use GROUP BY to sort the output.

Comment: nope..this is the same solution i tried earlier..but thats not it :( thanks for the reply :)