# Multiple join and count

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I was trying to get multiple counts of occuring fields from 2 or more tables and I solved that issue from this question,

[Nested queries to get count with two conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264581/nested-queries-to-get-count-with-two-conditions)

The solution worked but when tried in the following data structure,

It executes but never displays any result. but with the previous question i posted this kind of solution worked fine..Can anyone please help on this issue..it doesn't even say there is a syntax error.

**EDIT: sql query**

```
SELECT t1.timeStamp, t1.localIp, t2.localPort, t3.localGeo, t4.isp, t5.foreignIp, t6.foreignPort, t7.foreignGeo, t8.infection,t1.timeStampCount, t1.localIpCount, t2.localPortCount, t3.localGeoCount, t4.ispCount, t5.foreignIpCount, t6.foreignPortCount, t7.foreignGeoCount, t8.infectionCount
FROM
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(timeStamp) AS 'timeStampCount',COUNT(localIp) AS 'localIpCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
) c  
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp)t1  
JOIN 
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(localPort) AS 'localPortCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
) c  
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort)t2  
ON t1.timeStamp=t2.timeStamp 
JOIN 
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(localGeo) AS 'localGeoCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
) c  
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo)t3  
ON t1.timeStamp=t3.timeStamp 
JOIN 
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(isp) AS 'ispCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
) c  
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp)t4  
ON t1.timeStamp=t4.timeStamp 
JOIN 
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(foreignIp) AS 'foreignIpCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
) c  
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp)t5  
ON t1.timeStamp=t5.timeStamp 
JOIN 
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(foreignPort) AS 'foreignPortCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
) c  
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort)t6  
ON t1.timeStamp=t6.timeStamp 
JOIN 
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(foreignGeo) AS 'foreignGeoCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
) c  
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo)t7  
ON t1.timeStamp=t7.timeStamp JOIN 
(SELECT timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection,COUNT(infection) AS 'infectionCount' 
FROM (
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', port AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', "" AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS 'timeStamp', ip AS 'localIp', "" AS 'localPort', "" AS 'localGeo', "" AS 'isp', "" AS 'foreignIp', "" AS 'foreignPort', "" AS 'foreignGeo', Formatreport AS 'infection'  
    FROM tbl_www_cymru_com 
    ) c  
    GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection)t8 
ON t1.timeStamp=t8.timeStamp ORDER BY timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection
```

Comment: Add output format to generate query

Comment: can  you not run individual queries yourself and see where's the troublesome part?

Comment: thank you for your responses @SaharshShah wht do you mean by generate query

Comment: thank you for the reply .. @nawfal yeaa..am working on it.. :)

Comment: @nawfal well the inside `unions` and the outer `select , group by` statements that surround the unions work..one working means the rest is ok also cz i generate this query from c#

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it looks to me as if you should have a look at the `GRUP BY … WITH ROLLUP` feature. That will allow you to group by manx details, but also calculate totals for fewer details. Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/644e2/21

Comment: @MvG THank you for the reply..but im not looking for a output as you've shown..in my question, i have posted a link on a question i asked before..i need to get an out put like what i have shown there :)

Comment: Your current query joins by `timeStamp` only. So if you have 3 IPs for a given timestamp, and 2 ports for one of these IPs, then the join of `t1` and `t2` alone would lead to 12 result rows, some of them containing one ip from `t1` but a port number for a different ip from `t2`. Shouldn't you be joining on more columns?

Comment: @MvG  well, what i need is to get the `count` of `matching columns` which is in the `same hour` for a each `ip`..soo...is this approach wrong?? since its a huge query (for me) am also a bit confused right now :P

Comment: @MvG as in if there are two identical `ip's` within the `same hour`, the query should return the `total count` of matching `timestamp`, `ip`, `port`, `infection` ... and the rest of the available fields and show as `2` records with the `counts` as shown in my prev. question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264581/nested-queries-to-get-count-with-two-conditions :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/061e5/6 has two queries. Which is more like what you want? The first matches incrementally, i.e. first time, then time and ip, then time, ip and infection (for demo I left out the others). The second matches each individually, i.e. first by time, second my ip only, third by indection only.

Comment: @MvG thank you very much for your replies..i was out of tow and sorry for the delay...i will check your solution and inform you then you can post it as an answer :)

Comment: @MvG Hi, your first solution in  the link worked great after minor modifications..Thank you very much..it would be great if you could post it as the answer.. :) so i can mark it... :)

Comment: how may hours is it taking to get the o/p

Comment: wht u mean by o/p ?? @ArunKillu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first try to restate your question in my own words, to make it clear what this answer here does. For each record in the union of two tables, you want one row in the result set. That row should contain additional information: for a given set of selected columns you want to count the rows from the input which match the current rows in all selected columns. In each step you add to the set of selected rows. So first you count all rows with the same time stamp. Next you count all the rows with the same time stamp *and* the same IP address. And so on.

As you repeatedly select from the same union of tables, it might be prudent to introduce a short name for it. You can do so by [creating a `VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html). Next, you want to use that view as the first factor of your join. This gives you one row of output for every row of input. For the added statistics, you join to that a subquery which counts rows, grouping by all the selected columns for that count. You want to join that subquery to the rest of your query using all these selected columns. So for example:

```
CREATE VIEW view_both_tables AS
SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS `timeStamp`, ip AS localIp, …
FROM tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo 
UNION ALL 
SELECT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS `timeStamp`, ip AS localIp, …
FROM tbl_www_cymru_com;

SELECT t0.*,
 t1.countSameTime,
 t2.countSameTimeAndLocalIp,
 t3.countSameTimeLocalIpAndInfection
FROM view_both_tables t0
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `timeStamp`,
   COUNT(*) AS `countSameTime`
  FROM view_both_tables
  GROUP BY `timeStamp`
 ) t1 USING (`timeStamp`)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `timeStamp`, localIp,
   COUNT(*) AS `countSameTimeAndLocalIp`
  FROM view_both_tables
  GROUP BY `timeStamp`, localIp
 ) t2 USING (`timeStamp`, localIp)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `timeStamp`, localIp, infection,
   COUNT(*) AS `countSameTimeLocalIpAndInfection`
  FROM view_both_tables
  GROUP BY `timeStamp`, localIp, infection
 ) t3 USING (`timeStamp`, localIp, infection)
;
```

This query was taken from [my SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/061e5/6). It only covers up to three selected columns, as the other columns didn't contain any data in your example, and as the idea should be clear from this.

In general, it is more efficient to `COUNT(*)` instead of counting one particular column. The only exceptions are when the column you want to count may contain `NULL` values which should be omitted from the count, or when you're using `COUNT(DISTINCT …)`. But as my interpretation of your question referred to counting records, not rows, neither of these exceptions applies.

As a further note on style, using single quotation marks to quote column names is rather confusing SQL style. Usually, [strings are delimited using single quotation marks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html), and [columns uisng backticks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html). What you wrote is valid syntax for the default MySQL configuration, but confusing nonetheless.

If performance is an issue, you might try executing a single query using `GROUP BY … WITH ROLLUP`. Storing the result to a temporary table, you could derive the result you asked for from repeatedly joining that table to itself. No sure whether there would be any performance gain, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation...yea performance is an issue as i have to work with 1000s  of records..yeaa will give it a shot :) thanks again much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, i was trying to optimize the query and i tried `creating views` for every `select statement` inside the `join condition` and `joining the views`. which cut down the execution time to `13ms` from `38ms`..but this is for like 30 records with half the columns selected. but when i select all the columns and use all the 12000 records i have it takes forever to execute..any ideas to optimize the speed more if its possible?? thank you very much :)

Comment: @Hasitha, as I wrote, using a single query `WITH ROLLUP` to do all the aggregation might help, but you'll have to try. Other than that, adding indices is the obvious solution. Add one index for all the columns you use in your matching, in the order you use them, i.e. starting with timestamp. To do this, you might have to actually store this up-to-the-hour timestamp in your db. Or you have to join using some more elaborate syntax which constructs a ``WHERE `timestamp` IN RANGE …`` kind of condition.

Comment: Okeyyy :) thank you.. i will try more on this..thank you very much :)

Comment: so i put the data in the two tables to one table called `tbl_union_threats` instead of the `view` and adding index like this, `CREATE INDEX idx_correlate ON tbl_union_threats(timeStamp, localIp, localport, localgeo, isp, foreignip, foreignPort, foreigngeo, infection)` to it would speed it up a little right? is that what i meant :) thank you